# Single table or seperate table for each user to hold similar records? (performance??)

Tags: mysql

I have 2 scenarios for a MySQL DB and I'm not sure which to choose, and I've run into the same dilemma for a few tables.

I'm making a web application only accessed by members. Each member has their own deals, expenses, and say "listings".  The criteria for the records is the same across users, but each user can have completely different amounts of records.

My 2 scenarios are whether I should have one table for deals, one table for listings, one table for expenses...and have a field in each that links to the primary key for a particular user. Or...if it is better to have a separate deal table, expense table, and listing table for each user..(using a combined string like "user"+deals, or "user"+exp).  Deals can be used across 1 or 2 users, but expenses and listings are completely independent. I am going to have a master deal table to hold all the info for each deal, but there is a user deal table(s) that links their primary key to a deal primary key.

So, separate tables or one table?  If there are thousands of users with hundreds of deals/expenses/listings..I just don't want the queries to be extremely slow after a lot of deals or expenses have built up...No user will ever need to view anything from other users...strictly just their data.

Also, I'm familiar with how a database works and stores data, but I'm not 100% clear.  I just want it to work quickly, so my other question is (although it may be stupid) when a user submits a new deal or expense...is it inserted in the beginning or end the table? Or is it irrelevant...because a query will search everything in the table either way before returning information?

Answer (score 3):

Always use one table to store one kind of entity.

Or more specifically, what you're talking about is a nasty, complicated optimisation that works in an incredibly small subset of cases which almost certainly isn't yours.

You want to use just one table for one kind of entry. Index it appropriately, and try to get rid of old records when you don't need them any more.

Also, a lot of peoples' idea of "big data" isn't actually particularly big. Databases normally need little optimisation while their data still fit in RAM, which on a modern system means, say, 32Gb.

Comment: Thanks for the input.  I wasn't sure how big was actually big.  I guess 100,000 records of purely text isn't all that large for modern systems?  Even if there are many fields.  I appreciate the help because I didn't mind doing it either way, with one of multiple tables. The only issue was switching later if I had an issue (that would be an incredible hassle).  My only other issue is I will need to keep the records for at least 10 years. So removing old entries could be an issue. Maybe an archive table could help. Thanks again!

Comment: I just came here to see if it is reasonable to have one table say per user, to avoid 1) locking of other users 2) to prevent "dirty reads" (reading of partially commited data). Say, how does facebook do that? :D

Comment: You don't need to consider how Facebook does things because you aren't Facebook. Or at least, you don't have 100M users.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your second question:

In MySql the order of the records on the disk is defined by your `PRIMARY KEY`. Meaning a record does not get inserted at the end or the beginning, but rather wherever it belongs based on the primary key.

In other db's you have th option to use `CLUSTERED KEYS` in order to use another key than the  `PRIMARY` to order the records on disk, but this is not supported in MySql to my knowledge.

Regarding your first question:

I found myself in this position a couple of times and recently I keep getting back to one blog post (last of a series, the conclusion is in the bottom):
http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2011/01/03/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-3-table-per-concrete-type-tpc-and-choosing-strategy-guidelines.aspx

I quote:

> Before we get into this discussion, I
>   want to emphasize that there is no one
>   single "best strategy fits all
>   scenarios" exists. As you saw, each of
>   the approaches have their own
>   advantages and drawbacks. Here are
>   some rules of thumb to identify the
>   best strategy in a particular
>   scenario:
>
> - If you don’t require polymorphic associations or queries, lean toward
>     TPC—in other words, if you never or
>     rarely query for BillingDetails and
>     you have no class that has an
>     association to BillingDetail base
>     class. I recommend TPC (Table per Concrete Type) (only) for the
>     top level of your class hierarchy,
>     where polymorphism isn’t usually
>     required, and when modification of the
>     base class in the future is unlikely.
> - If you do require polymorphic associations or queries, and
>     subclasses declare relatively few
>     properties (particularly if the main
>     difference between subclasses is in
>     their behavior), lean toward TPH (Table per  Hierarchy). Your
>     goal is to minimize the number of
>     nullable columns and to convince
>     yourself (and your DBA) that a
>     denormalized schema won’t create
>     problems in the long run.
> - If you do require polymorphic associations or queries, and
>     subclasses declare many properties
>     (subclasses differ mainly by the data
>     they hold), lean toward TPT (Table per Type). Or,
>     depending on the width and depth of
>     your inheritance hierarchy and the
>     possible cost of joins versus unions,
>     use TPC.
>
> By default, choose TPH only for simple
>   problems. For more complex cases (or
>   when you’re overruled by a data
>   modeler insisting on the importance of
>   nullability constraints and
>   normalization), you should consider
>   the TPT strategy. But at that point,
>   ask yourself whether it may not be
>   better to remodel inheritance as
>   delegation in the object model
>   (delegation is a way of making
>   composition as powerful for reuse as
>   inheritance). Complex inheritance is
>   often best avoided for all sorts of
>   reasons unrelated to persistence or
>   ORM. EF acts as a buffer between the
>   domain and relational models, but that
>   doesn’t mean you can ignore
>   persistence concerns when designing
>   your classes.

Comment: You could add to your answer that the clustered index is supported for InnoDB tables but not for MyIsam.